# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object in uptime kuma

Tags: python, uptime-kuma

i am running a python script but got following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/himanshus/nginx/uptime.py", line 6, in <module>
    result = api.add_monitor(type=str(MonitorType.HTTP), name="google", url="https://google.com")
  File "/home/himanshus/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uptime_kuma_api/api.py", line 1465, in add_monitor
    data = self._build_monitor_data(**kwargs)
  File "/home/himanshus/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uptime_kuma_api/api.py", line 810, in _build_monitor_data
    if parse_version(self.version) >= parse_version("1.22"):
  File "/home/himanshus/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/version.py", line 52, in parse
    return Version(version)
  File "/home/himanshus/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/version.py", line 196, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

i have tried possible ways but isssue is inside the python code so not sure what to dp

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.